# insert into database using dynamic form

Tags: php

i`m trying to insert a data into database from a dynamic form, the data is being inserted sucsessfully but only the newest input field will being added to the database (example : i add a new input to the form using the button in the web, the data that being inserted is only the new input, meanwhile the input before the new one doesnt inserted).

```
<?php 
include 'config/db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $i=0;
     foreach($_POST['kp_berjangka'] as $value){
    // insert query values can be fetched by
$file = $_POST['file'];
$selectidmax =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT max(id_kebijakan) as maxidadmin FROM t_kebijakan WHERE id_kebijakan LIKE 'KO%'");
$hslidmax=mysqli_fetch_array($selectidmax);
$idmax=$hslidmax['maxidadmin'];
$nourut = (int) substr($idmax, 2,3);
$nourut++;
$IDbaru = "KO" . sprintf("%03s", $nourut);
$kp_saham = $_POST['kp_saham'][$i];
$pro_saham = $_POST['produk_saham'][$i];
$bung_saham = $_POST['bunga_saham'][$i];
$ket_saham = $_POST['ket_saham'][$i];
$kp_harian = $_POST['kp_harian'][$i];
$pro_harian = $_POST['produk_harian'][$i];
$bung_harian = $_POST['bunga_harian'][$i];
$ket_harian = $_POST['ket_harian'][$i];
$kp_berjangka = $_POST['kp_berjangka'][$i];
$pro_berjangka = $_POST['produk_berjangka'][$i];
$bung_berjangka = $_POST['bunga_berjangka'][$i];
$ket_berjangka = $_POST['ket_berjangka'][$i];
$kp_deposito = $_POST['kp_deposito'][$i];
$pro_deposito = $_POST['produk_deposito'][$i];
$bung_deposito = $_POST['bunga_deposito'][$i];
$ket_deposito = $_POST['ket_deposito'][$i];
$kp_pinjaman = $_POST['kp_pinjaman'][$i];
$pro_pinjaman = $_POST['produk_pinjaman'][$i];
$bung_pinjaman = $_POST['bunga_pinjaman'][$i];
$ket_pinjaman = $_POST['ket_pinjaman'][$i];
$id = $_POST['meja'][$i];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_kebijakan (id_kebijakan, file, kp_saham, produk_saham, bunga_saham, keterangan_saham, kp_harian, produk_harian, bunga_harian, keterangan_harian, kp_berjangka, produk_berjangka, bunga_berjangka, keterangan_berjangka, kp_deposito, produk_deposito, bunga_deposito, keterangan_deposito, kp_pinjaman, produk_pinjaman, bunga_pinjaman, keterangan_pinjaman, kode_cu) 
    VALUES (
    '$IDbaru',
    '$file',
    '$kp_saham',
    '$pro_saham',
    '$bung_saham',
    '$ket_saham',
    '$kp_harian',
    '$pro_harian',
    '$bung_harian',
    '$ket_harian',
    '$kp_berjangka',
    '$pro_berjangka',
    '$bung_berjangka',
    '$ket_berjangka',
    '$kp_deposito',
    '$pro_deposito',
    '$bung_deposito',
    '$ket_deposito',
    '$kp_pinjaman',
    '$pro_pinjaman',
    '$bung_pinjaman',
    '$ket_pinjaman',
    '$id'
    )");
    }


if($query){
    header('location: home_cu.php');
}else{
    echo "data gagal dimasukan" . mysqli_error($con) . mysqli_errno($con);
}

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Add More Input Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php 
    include 'config/db_connect.php';
    $kode_cu = $_GET['kode_cu'];
    $query_mysql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM t_cu WHERE kode_cu='$kode_cu'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $nomor = 1;
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_mysql)){
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Tambah Data Kebijakan</h1>
        <form action="add_kebijakan.php" method="post">
        <h1 class="text-left">File</h1>
        <div class="form-content">
        <label>File :</label>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['kode_cu']?>" name="meja[]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
                <h1 class="text-center">Produk Simpanan Saham</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_saham[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk_saham[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga_saham[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket_saham[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Produk Simpanan Harian</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_harian[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk_harian[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga_harian[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket_harian[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Produk Simpanan Berjangka</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_berjangka[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk_berjangka[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga_berjangka[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket_berjangka[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Produk Simpanan Deposito</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_deposito[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk_deposito[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga_deposito[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket_deposito[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-center">Produk Pinjaman</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_pinjaman[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk_pinjaman[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga_pinjaman[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket_pinjaman[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Simpan</button>
            </p><br/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.multifield.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.form-content').multifield({
            section: '.group',
            btnAdd:'#btnAdd',
            btnRemove:'.btnRemove',
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the result after i added `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['kp_saham']);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ADS
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ADS
)
Array
(
    [0] => ADS
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ADS
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => AD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(




[0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
)
Array
(
    [0] => CO001
)
```

note : the ASD, ADS is just word that type randomly

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum we need to solve your problem

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you have used jquery multifield js to generate certain form fields multiple time. To save multiple records you have to do following steps.

1.Create array of controls by adding `[]` in the name of input control i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="kp_berjangka[]" class="form-control"/>
```

This need to be done with all input fields which need to be stored in database

2.While processing post request you need to save data using loop. Code will be similar like this.
i.e.

```
 $i=0;
 foreach($_POST['kp_berjangka'] as $value){
    // insert query values can be fetched by
    $IDbaru = "KO" . sprintf("%03s", $nourut);
    $kp_saham = $_POST['kp_saham'][$i];
    $pro_saham = $_POST['produk_saham'][$i];
    $bung_saham = $_POST['bunga_saham'][$i];
    $ket_saham = $_POST['ket_saham'][$i];
    $kp_harian = $_POST['kp_harian'][$i];
    $pro_harian = $_POST['produk_harian'][$i];
    $bung_harian = $_POST['bunga_harian'][$i];
    $ket_harian = $_POST['ket_harian'][$i];
    $kp_berjangka = $_POST['kp_berjangka'][$i];
    $pro_berjangka = $_POST['produk_berjangka'][$i];
    $bung_berjangka = $_POST['bunga_berjangka'][$i];
    $ket_berjangka = $_POST['ket_berjangka'][$i];
    $kp_deposito = $_POST['kp_deposito'][$i];
    $pro_deposito = $_POST['produk_deposito'][$i];
    $bung_deposito = $_POST['bunga_deposito'][$i];
    $ket_deposito = $_POST['ket_deposito'][$i];
    $kp_pinjaman = $_POST['kp_pinjaman'][$i];
    $pro_pinjaman = $_POST['produk_pinjaman'][$i];
    $bung_pinjaman = $_POST['bunga_pinjaman'][$i];
    $ket_pinjaman = $_POST['ket_pinjaman'][$i];
    $id = $_POST['meja'][$i];

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_kebijakan (id_kebijakan, file, kp_saham, produk_saham, bunga_saham, keterangan_saham, kp_harian, produk_harian, bunga_harian, keterangan_harian, kp_berjangka, produk_berjangka, bunga_berjangka, keterangan_berjangka, kp_deposito, produk_deposito, bunga_deposito, keterangan_deposito, kp_pinjaman, produk_pinjaman, bunga_pinjaman, keterangan_pinjaman, kode_cu) 
        VALUES (
        '$IDbaru',
        '$file',
        '$kp_saham',
        '$pro_saham',
        '$bung_saham',
        '$ket_saham',
        '$kp_harian',
        '$pro_harian',
        '$bung_harian',
        '$ket_harian',
        '$kp_berjangka',
        '$pro_berjangka',
        '$bung_berjangka',
        '$ket_berjangka',
        '$kp_deposito',
        '$pro_deposito',
        '$bung_deposito',
        '$ket_deposito',
        '$kp_pinjaman',
        '$pro_pinjaman',
        '$bung_pinjaman',
        '$ket_pinjaman',
        '$id'
    )");
}
```

By using this loop you will get all record submitted by forms.

3.You can not save file using `$_POST['FILE']` please check file uploading process from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp This will help you

Comment: your code only inserted the first recored, the record that being added from the `add more` button doesn`t inserted into the database, i will update my question for the updated code

Answer (score 2):

In this part or the others try to add `[]` in the `name` of input. example

```
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kp_berjangka[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

then in your form action do this

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['kp_saham']);
```

Comment: `echo "<pre>";print_r($kp_berjangka); ` do you mean replacing `$kp_saham = $_POST['kp_saham'];` with that?

Comment: for now don't replace it. Just add `die()` below my script. and try check the input.

Comment: and if i replace it with 'echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['kp_saham']);' , what should i put in the values inside the query?

Comment: i just want to see the value(s) for now.

Comment: @InFocus so , is  `[0] => CO001` part your $_POST['kp_saham']` ?

Comment: no, `[0] => CO001` is part of my `$_POST['kode_cu']`